# How can I center this responsive layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a new portfolio website for myself, using a wordpress theme that I've modified to suit my needs. The website can be found [here](http://www.finlaydownes.com).

The site is mostly doing what I want it to do, but at the moment the individual posts on the homepage are aligned to the left. What I want them to do is to distribute themselves in the center of the page. Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure this out with my limited knowledge of css.

The CSS in question (I think):

```
#post-area .post { 
    width:310px; 
    background:#FFF; 
    margin-right:10px; 
    margin-top:15px; 
    position:relative; 
}

#post-area .post .gridly-copy { 
    width:250px; 
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto; 
    padding-top:10px; 
    padding-bottom:20px; 
    overflow:hidden; clear:both;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm (clearly) not a web developer, so please bear with me if any of this sounds silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the masonry jQuery script, which has the option to center the content instead of aligning it to the left. If you go to the site (http://masonry.desandro.com/) there is an option for the columns to be centered. (Unfortunately, the site is down for me right now, but hopefully it will be up again shorty.)

You really need to use that solution, because the boxes are set to `position: absolute`, so trying to override the current styling would be a nightmare (if even possible).

EDIT: Short of that site coming back, you could try some experiments. See if you can find this file in your system: http://www.finlaydownes.com/wp-content/themes/gridly/js/functions.js?ver=3.5.1

It includes this code:

```
// masonry code 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#post-area').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.post',
    // options...
  isAnimated: true,
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 400,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false
  }

  });
});
```

Try changing that to this:

```
// masonry code 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#post-area').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.post',
    // options...
  isAnimated: true,
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 400,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false
  },
  isFitWidth: true

  });
});
```

I just added `isFitWidth: true`, which worked for me recently to center the Masonry layout. Hope that helps. (Make sure to include the comma before that line I added.)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! The site is down for me too, but hopefully that will be enough for me to go on.

Comment: I've edited my post with a solution you can try. It worked for me recently. :-)

Comment: Success! Thank you so much! I was looking everwhere for a place to put 'isFitWidth', but I working in jquery.masonry.min.js. :P

As a side note, I also needed to add some automatic margins to the post area, in case anyone else is having a similar problem.